# Clone an Ubuntu machine with software RAID

Tags: raid, rsync, mdadm, dd, clone

I need to migrate my dedicated server to a new one:

- Both server are hosted remotely, I've no access to physical machines, only root ssh
- The old server is running Ubuntu server 13.10, 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/
- The old server have software RAID ( /dev/md )
- The new server have hardware RAID!!!!
- The new server have larger disk and different partitioning (it's a new Ubuntu 13.10 clean install)

What is the best way to clone all the installation to a remote machine?

Is rsync of the root directory a good way? What subdirs I've to exculde considering I've the software raid on the old server and hardware raid on the new one, so I don't want mdadm configuration to be copied to the new one.

Comment: It would be easier to do it piping tar over your ssh connection, but it looks like you want rsync.

Comment: Have you looked at [dd](http://ss64.com/bash/dd.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry with providing no real answer, but I think I can provide at least some help as I wrote a script to copy ubuntu systems. I did not published this script though, because it is not perfect until now! So please be careful!

Read all configuration parameters and comments carefully. Maybe you don't want to use the script at all, but investigate the skipped paths only that are not possible/needed to rsync.
Most important step is to manually adjust the /etc/fstab after successfully copy of the system.
Also I don't quite understand - you wanna clone into a running system?? I am not sure if this will work.

Nevertheless, here is the script:

http://www.nskcomputing.de/index.php?section=Download&id=copytux

But again: the script is in beta stage, be very very careful!

Regarding the hardware raid, try to find out whether the raid controller is supported natively or if there is an additional driver or kernel module to support the controller.